# EF Core 7 Combine Expression and Id in a single query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm writing an aggregation services and to reduce code repetitions, for a column of an object (entity) I have a method which will return `Expression<Func<MyEntity,decimal>>`.

Now, it's really easy to use for sorting and filtering, but I can't find a way to use it in a combined select.

For example:  this line works and generates the correct SQL:

```
var results123 = await _com.Bookings
                           .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
                           .Select(exp).ToListAsync();
```

Note that `_com` is an EF Core 7 context, `Bookings` is a `DbSet` mapped to a table, and `exp` is of type `Expression<Func<BookingProfile, double>>`.

But in my context, I need also to get Ids. So, I need to modify `.Select` in a way that provides `Id` and `Expression` result values.

I already tried (with no results) :

```
var results123 = await _com.Bookings
                           .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
                           .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                           .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.AsQueryable().Select(exp));


// results = await _scopedCache.GetItemAndCacheIt("bookings_" + column, async () => await _com.Bookings
    //    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    //    .Select(x => new { x.Id, Result = exp.Compile()(x) }) // Select both Id and result of expression
    //    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Result));
```

I feel like it's something obvious that I'm missing.

**Note**: I did though about just ordering by Id as I have Ids list and I can order results then match them. But it feels messy and not always reusable.

Thanks.

Edit :

This solution works, but I really don't like how it's writen. (It does seems to produce good SQL tho)

Any idea on how to make it great ?

```
 var results444 = await _com.Bookings.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => new
        {
            x.Id,
            Sum = _com.Bookings.Where(xx => xx.Id == x.Id).Select(exp).SingleOrDefault()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You need LINQKit and its method `Expand` or `Invoke`. With vanilla EF Core it is not possible.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it, but I do not want to add more external references th an needed for now. I'm pretty sure it should be possible without Expand.  (Invoke is a part of vanilla c# tho)

Comment: You can write interceptor and do LINQKit's job by yourself. EF Core cannot translate query because it sees not your expression but `MemberAccss` to your variable which contains expression. Ideally It should access to this variable and get expression, but this is not included in EF Core's translation process.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thanks again ! I do like what I see in the docs for LINQKit. I will explore it. BTW, I added an Edit with a code wghich works, but it just seems a bit "hacky"

Answer (score -1):

You need your expression to instead be a `Expression<Func<MyEntity, IdAndValue>>` where `IdAndValue` is a type containing those two columns. Then you can do

```cs
var results123 = await _com.Bookings
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(exp)
    .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Id, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing how you are computing the existing Sum, you should be able to get the desired effect by using an `Expression<Func<Booking, dynamic>>` where you set up the expression to something like:

```
Expression<Func<Booking, dynamic>> exp = x => new 
{ 
    x.Id, 
    ItemValueSum = x.SomeItems.Sum(i => i.Value) 
};
```

then when passed in, it can be used in the `Select`

```
var results = await _com.Bookings
    .Where(x => bookingIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(exp)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This would return the booking Id and whatever this value sum you are computing. It compiles with `Expression<Func<Booking, object>>` as well, but you would need to force a cast back using an instance type before you could access the values if you want a strongly typed result. (probably better to use a projected concrete model in that case)

Edit: With the concrete result model:

Declared result object:

```
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public decimal SomeSum { get; set; }
}
```

computed expression to pass in...

```
Expression<Func<Booking, Result>> exp = x => new 
{ 
    Id = x.Id, 
    SomeSum = x.SomeItems.Sum(i => i.Value) 
};
```

then executed:

```
var results = await _com.Bookings
    .Where(x => bookingIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .Select(exp)
    .ToListAsync();
```